# Une traduction pour « grondlichaam », une notion algébrique

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, terminologie, mathématiques, néerlandais

Il me manque mot  qui traduit un nom commun néerlandais. Je le décris ci-dessous.

Si *K* est un corps algébrique, et *f* est un polynôme à coefficients dans *K*, alors on peut étendre ce corps en ajoutant une racine *a* de *f* qui n'appartient pas à *K*. On écrit *K(a)* pour désigner le plus petit corps qui comprenne *a* et le corps qu’on étudiait au premier lieu.

Un corps semblable à *K(a)* est dit un « corps d’extension ». Dans ce cadre, on a besoin d’un mot à part qui désigne *K*, pour éviter des malentendus. Aux Pays-Bas ont utilise souvent un mot qui veut dire « corps de base », mais cette traduction littérale prête trop à confusion. J’utilise donc « corps antérieur » mais je n’ai pas trouvé d'ouvrage qui affirme avec certitude que cet emploi convienne.  Pouvez-vous me donner des renseignements ?

Comment: Petite note, plutôt que « corps d'extension » on dit généralement « extension de corps ». (Dans ce cas précis, c'est même une extension algébrique simple)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je ne trouve pas de mot ou d'expression consacrée, ni dans ma mémoire, ni sur [Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_de_corps) (une bonne ressource pour des traductions de termes techniques quand ils sont suffisamment répandus), ni dans le *Dictionnaire des mathématiques* de Bouvier, George et Le Lionnais.

Le moins ambigu est encore d'utiliser une notation mathématique : « le corps *K* ». Parler du « corps de base » me semble raisonnable (mais il vaut mieux préciser « le corps de base *K* » la première fois). En revanche, je ne comprendrais pas « le corps antérieur » sans une définition, et le choix de mot me semble mauvais parce qu'il n'évoque pas le bon concept (*antérieur* fait plutôt référence à un ordre temporel). On peut aussi dire « le sous-corps », mais cela devient ambigu rapidement, alors que « corps de base » sera compris sans problème dans une discussion qui parle de *K*, *K(a)* et *K(a,b)*.

---

Quelques formulations dans la question qui sont compréhensibles mais pas du tout idiomatiques :

- « un polynôme qu'y tire ses coefficients » → « un polynôme à coefficients dans *K* ». La formule n'est pas grammaticalement correcte, il manque un sujet à « tire ». On devine « un polynôme qui y tire ses coefficients », mais ce n'est pas idiomatique : on n'utilise « tirer » qu'à la voix passive (« un polynôme dont les coefficients sont tirés dans ce corps »), mais ce n'est pas idiomatique ici, on dira juste que les coefficients sont dans le corps.
- « qui gît en dehors » → « qui n'appartient pas à *K* » (ou à la rigueur « qui se situe en dehors »). En tout cas pas *gésir*, qui en français moderne ne s'utilise guère que pour les morts.

Comment: Merci. Quant à gésir, voulez-vous dire que le mot est vieilli lui-même , ou dites vous que mon emploi est suranné ? Deuxièmement, ai-je retiré les fautes comme il faut ?

Comment: Je confirme qu'on dit souvent « le corps de base », probablement parce qu'une extension de *K* est aussi un *K*-espace vectoriel.

Comment: Voilà ce qui me paraît un peu flou : Les vecteurs qui engendrent le corps *K(a)* n’appartiennent pas à *K*, tandis que le « corps de base » est *K*.

Comment: @Evpok Je ne vois pas le rapport avec les espaces vectoriels ; le mot *base* n'a pas de rapport entre les deux sens.

Comment: @KoenraadvanDuin J'ai corrigé quelques autres phrases dans la question. Pour *gésir*, c'est les deux : en français courant, on ne l'emploie plus guère qu'à l'indicatif présent et pour un cadavre ; en français littéraire, on peut utiliser d'autres temps et généraliser le sens, mais le verbe tend quand même à évoquer la mort.

Comment: @Gilles Quand on a un *K*-espace vectoriel *E*, on dit que *K* est le corps de base de *E*. C'est dans ce sens là que je l'entends.

Comment: « Corps de base » dans le cas des extensions de corps est attesté chez Bourbaki (*Algèbre*, p. A V.183) et chez Serre (*Cohomologie galoisienne*, p. 82).